# What is the most popular design-patterns in web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, web-applications, architecture

What is the most popular design pattern in web app?

I know that in asp.net mvc often used dependency injection and repository, but I want to know which additional patterns can I use in web apps. And it would be best if you give me sample of situation in which I can use  patterns, or give code snippet.

Comment: The most popular pattern is to get drunk and bump into friends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the design patterns we've developed as software engineers over the last few decades are still applicable for the situations they were designed for. Depending on your needs you will use most of these in web apps at some point.

http://geekswithblogs.net/subodhnpushpak/archive/2009/09/18/the-23-gang-of-four-design-patterns-.-revisited.aspx

Also below is a link to a site that shows quite a few of these patterns and has explanations / examples. They have their own product, which the site is a shop front for, but the site does have examples and contain code samples so may be worth a visit if you feel like it. most in C#

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Singleton is the most popular pattern. It is also one of best know *anti-pattern* (patterns that are considered to be harmful).

Every newbie uses it, because it lets you use [global state](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI), that *looks* like object oriented code. It also lets you avoid, that confusing [dependency injection](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0) thing.

As for the *"Gang of Four"* book, there has been a movement by some [uneducated people](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/OOPSLA2004.html) to remove the Singleton pattern in latest editions, but the attempts has been successfully thwarted.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you have $28... [C# Design Strategies with Jon Skeet](http://tekpub.com/productions/cspatterns)

I haven't watched it but I do plan to buy it soon.

edit: IMHO the most popular design pattern in asp.net web development is the [Smart UI anti-pattern](http://geekswithblogs.net/gregorymalcolm/archive/2009/07/14/user-interface-patterns.aspx) ;)